# Individual websites and apps not available on all computers in the WiFi network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, debug

For a few days now, I have systematically been unable to access specific websites on all devices in my home WiFi network. Specific apps are affected as well. All other sites and apps work as desired. There is no system-wide firewall in place and no changes to the system were made when the error began occurring. I have restarted all systems several times.

What could be the cause of this problem? Any hints are much appreciated.

Comment: A list of which devices can and can't use which apps and websites would be helpful, so we can help you spot trends.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be either on your router or upstream (ie ISP or  government blocking). The first thing I would try is rebooting your router, then trying a friends.  If the problem persists, call your ISP.